# GRASS within QGIS - v.buffer.distance adding additional parameters

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, buffer

My end aim is to perform a buffer without end caps (-c) and straight corners (-s) based on a distance field. Neither of these options are available within the module options in the GUI within QGIS, is there any way to add these anywhere within the GUI?

[image]

I have also tried running GRASS within the regular processing toolbox but keep getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest reinstalling QGIS using the *OSGeo4W Network Installer* and selecting the `Advanced Install`  option. Follow the on-screen instructions until you reach the *Select Packages* page. Select `Desktop` and make sure the GRASS releases are/will be installed:

[image: Select packages]

Once the installation is complete, load QGIS, make sure the **Processing** plugin is enabled (it should be), then from the menubar go to:

```
Processing > Options... > Providers
```

Find the two GRASS providers, make sure they're activated and insert the path of their associated folder:

[image: GRASS folder]

Click *OK* and hopefully now you should not have the "dependency" error. I just tested this myself and the `v.buffer.distance` tool from GRASS7 works for me (first time I ever used a working tool from GRASS7!)

Comment: Thank you Joseph, a really clear answer. My GRASS GIS 7 commands folder is blank and I cannot define it, however my regular GRASS folder is populated and I can now run the tools.

Comment: @AlanCarr - Most welcome! You need to double-click the command folder in order to define it but glad the regular GRASS tools work :)

Comment: Quick question, what is the proper width/unit to use for the distance column? I'm currently using "1 metres" "3/4 metres" etc. as it works in ArcGIS. I cannot find any example of acceptable units within any of the documentation.

Comment: If the units of your CRS is in metres then you can just type `1` or `0.75`.

Comment: I repeated exactly what you've indicated here - using QGIS 2.18.25 and retaining that version to keep LecoS plugin active. I cannot get this to work. I reviewed the log by running batch process and find this:geometry Name of geometry column 

ERROR: Sorry is not a valid option 

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region n=6247988.22195 s=5957293.66509 e=438398.898048 w=103021.608948 res=100 

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.buffer input="tmp15413109031817" distance="200" tolerance="0.01" -c output="output6294609a27d04633854f56e3efc9bfcb" --overwrite 
ERROR: Vector map not found

Comment: I think the only current / best solution is to upgrade to QGIS 3.2 [as described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290717/buffering-with-rectangular-end-caps-and-not-dissolving/290727), which worked for me. I just have to maintain a separate 2.18.25 to keep [LecoS](https://github.com/Martin-Jung/LecoS/issues/12) or other plugins functional until these are updated.

Comment: @MarkThompson - Thanks for your feedback. I think I used an earlier version of QGIS so perhaps there is an issue with the recent version? Regardless, I think you are correct in that using the latest QGIS version is the best solution ^^