# Buffering with rectangular end caps and not dissolving

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am using QGIS to attempt to achieve what should be a simple task.

I need to buffer a polygon layer with flat end caps, and without dissolving the resulting layer. In QGIS there are 3 tools for buffering:

- v.buffer GRASS command
- Fixed Distance buffer in Vector > Geoprocessing
- GDAL Buffer vectors tool

v.buffer allows controlling the end cap style and whether the resulting layer is dissolved or not.

Fixed distance buffer in Vector > Geoprocessing outputs an undissolved buffer layer, however the edges are round and overlap. It doesn't seem possible to control the end cap type for the edges.

GDAL buffer vectors tool presents a similar problematic to Fixed distance buffer in Vector>Geoprocessing tools.

How do I achieve a discontinuous (undissolved) buffer with flat edges in the QGIS environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Upgrade to QGIS 3.2. 
The tools "buffer" offer what you achieve

[image]

Comment: They do. Just out of curiosity, this is simply not feasible using QGIS 2.18.20? How would you do it in an earlier version of QGIS?

Comment: May be with python ( see for exemple "https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41267/buffering-in-pyqgis") ? but it's out of my competences